# How to get the Stub URI of an ECL item from an external application

Tags: core-service, ecl

I am writing an application which will trigger workflow on any items that use ECL components when they are modified in the external content library. My original idea was to create a simple web service which receives messages from the external system with a signature something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Tridion.ContentManager;
using Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;
namespace UrbanCherry.Net.Tridion.ECL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ECLUpdateService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ECLUpdateService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// UpdateECLItem will recieve a message that an ECL item has changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mountPoint">ID of the mountpoint I want to use</param>
        /// <param name="itemID">External ID of the item</param>
        /// <param name="actionType">Update type (Delete or Update)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [WebMethod]
        public string UpdateECLItem(String mountPoint, String itemID, ActionType actionType)
        {
            //Do my magic
            return "OK";
        }

    }
}
```

My external id can easily be converted into the `ECLURI` as follows:

```
String eclItemID = "ecl:" + pubID + "-" + mountPoint + "-" + itemID + "-img-file";
```

The first thing my service needs to do is map the `ECLURI` to the `TCMURI` of the stub item. There seems to be no method for doing this using the Core Service, but I can achieve this by using the `SessionFactory` object as follows:

```
    Session  tcmSession = new Session();
    IEclSession eclSession = SessionFactory.CreateEclSession(tcmSession);
    String tcmURI = eclSession.TryGetTcmUriFromEclUri(eclSession.HostServices.CreateEclUri(eclItemID));
```

However, I understand that creating a new session object in external code is not supported/recommended. If this is really the case, the only solution I have is to create some kind of mapping database table to store the relationships. This seems like overkill when `eclSession.TryGetTcmUriFromEclUri()` does exactly what I need.
Can anyone think of how I can either execute `eclSession.TryGetTcmUriFromEclUri` from a supported context (which can be triggered from an external application), or mimic it in some other way without needing to create a custom lookup table?

Answer (score 4):

You have `SessionFactory.CreateEclSession(string username)`. You will need to make sure the usual core service bindings are available in the config for your process.

I would expect this method to be deprecated when (if) the `EclService` becomes a public interface, but then it will be according to standard deprecation policies giving you some time to get migrated. It will come with the penalty of spinning up a new TOM.NET process, so you can of course also try to use the `EclService` directly... but be prepared to make changes when upgrading to a new version of Tridion if you go down this path.

Comment: Thanks Lars, so will  SessionFactory.CreateEclSession(string username) use the core service or the same TOM.NET approach of creating a new Session? Do I need to copy the whole Tridion.ConentManager.config into my web.config, or just use the CoreService bindings?

Comment: It will use TOM.NET. I would think you can get away with referencing the main config file though. I would look in the config files of the Tridion processes to see if there was something I could be "inspired" by. :)